# Displaying image name under image using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have developed a page where i display image from the database along with its image name.

I managed to display the names and imagenames from the database successfully, but the images and imagenames are aligned like:

```
IMG1 IMG2 IMG3   IMGname1 IMGname2 IMGname3
```

The code i tried to display the images and its name from the database:

```
<div class='badgeicon'>
      <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM badges WHERE badge_id='$id_badge'";

       $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       $image_src2 = $row['badge_image'];
       $imagedes  = $row['description'];
      ?>
      <img src= "<?php echo  $image_src2;  ?>" width="130px" height="140px">

       <?php echo $imagedes; ?>
```

I expect the output to be :

```
IMG1       IMG2        IMG3 

IMGname1   IMGname2    IMGname3
```

i.e., with the imagenames directly under the respective images.

Comment: If you trying to achieve alignment try to put it inside an HTML table. Split the current loop into two loops. The first loop could print the first row ie the images and the second loop could print the second row descriptions.

Comment: That would be very inefficient @PrakashS

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to format with css.

```
<div class="image">
   <img src= "<?php echo  $image_src2;  ?>" width="130px" height="140px">
   <span class="description"><?php echo $imagedes; ?></span>
</div>
```

And here for the style

```
.image{
        display: inline-block;
    }

.description{
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

You can do a lot more depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: this is not inside a loop, therefor it would only show one image

Comment: @RamondeVries The idea is to put the html inside the loop, so there would exist multiple div.image on the page. I only dealt with the html and css not the original php.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should be what you are looking for, keeping the img and name in a loop:

```
<div class='badgeicon'>
      <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM badges WHERE badge_id='$id_badge'";

       $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
       $fetchresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       foreach($fetchresult as $row){
           echo '<img src="'.$row['badge_image'].'" width="130px" height="140px">';
           echo $row['description'];
       }
      ?>
```

Comment: i tried the code, it gives an error,"unexpected ')' on the line foreach

Comment: ur getting an unexpected ) still?

Comment: Yes... i get the same error unexpected ')' on line foreach

Comment: do you mind sharing the rest of the file?, since the foreach on it's own should be fine. i think there is something else making it turn into an error, in an jsfiddle if possible

Comment: my own foreaches look like this: `foreach($_POST['test'] as $option){
        echo $option;
    }`, just the same, and mine are working fine

Comment: therefor i think you missed an closeing tag somewhere else in your file

Comment: awesome, happy coding! :P